# Using xdotool or similar tool, how can I change window order?

Tags: x11

I need to tell window A to be displayed above window B, but below window C. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml#windowraise_window_id_1) (and changing stacking for C):

```
xdotool windowraise window_id A
xdotool windowraise window_id C
```

Comment: Helpful, but if there are numerous unknown windows on top of window C, they will go to the bottom.